# How to pass Activity to a react native module, inside getPackages method?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to `react-native` and would really like to create a module. For now I'm updating an outdated module. 
My general question is how to get the current activity when running a package?
The old way is using the `this` keyword to get the current activity inside `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
      .setApplication(getApplication())
      .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
      .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
      .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
      .addPackage(new ThePackageClass(this))              // <------ custom package
      .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
      .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "ExampleRN", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
  }
```

but this doesn't the case with the new updates of `react-native`. I dunno how to achieve it under the `getPackages` method.

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new ThePackageClass(this) <-- this here doesnt work
  );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getPackages` is method of `ReactNativeHost`, as well the ReactNativeHost has an reference of the Application, you can maintain an current front activity in the application class to achieve this.